# how to change selected item using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a html drop down as follwos

```
<select id="subCategory" class="style_1">
     <option name="All" value="16,17,19,18,8,94" >All</option>
     <option name="CBC" value="94" >CBC</option>
</select>
```

And i want to change the selected item using jquery as follows.

```
var subCategorySelected = "CBC";    
$('#subCategory').find('option:contains(' + subCategorySelected + ')').attr({selected: "selected"});
```

But its not working. Can anyone help me find the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your code is working!**

```js
var subCategorySelected = "CBC";    
$('#subCategory').find('option:contains(' + subCategorySelected + ')').attr({selected: "selected"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="subCategory" class="style_1">
     <option name="All" value="16,17,19,18,8,94" >All</option>
     <option name="CBC" value="94" >CBC</option>
</select>
```

Just make sure the code is executed after page is completely loaded. This can be done by using ***any*** of the following

1. Wrap the code in `ready` handler
2. Move the script to the end of `<body>`

---

[*`:contains`*](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) will check if the passed string is contained anywhere in the element. So, if there are multiple elements which contains the string, this will select wrong options.

**Example:**

```
<select>
    <option something="something">ABC DEF</option>
    <option something="something">ABC</option>
    <option something="something">ABC XYZ</option>
</select>
```

Here, to select `ABC` - the second option, if we use `:contains('ABC')`, this will select the other option.

You may use [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('#subCategory option[name="' + subCategorySelected + '"]').prop('selected', true);
```

The selector `option[name="' + subCategorySelected + '"]` will select the `<option>` element having `name` attribute value as the given value. Then `selected` property can be set using `prop()`.

```js
var subCategorySelected = "CBC";
$('#subCategory option[name="' + subCategorySelected + '"]').prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="subCategory" class="style_1">
     <option name="All" value="16,17,19,18,8,94" >All</option>
     <option name="CBC" value="94" >CBC</option>
</select>
```

---

If you have the mapping of option text and value, using value the option can be selected as

```
$('#subCategory').val('94');
```

Comment: Quick! Just avoid use of `can`, as it appears as what OP has done is also right...+1

Comment: @Rayon Thank you for the tips. I've updated answer. Didn't realize it was working code.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var subCategorySelected = "CBC";  
$('#subCategory option').filter(function() {

  return $(this).text() == subCategorySelected;


}).prop('selected', 'selected')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="subCategory" class="style_1">
  <option name="All" value="16,17,19,18,8,94">All</option>
  <option name="CBC" value="94">CBC</option>
</select>
```

Use `.filter()`

Answer (score 1):

Use the following selector ([CSS 3 style](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)) also please look at [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

`E[foo="bar"]`
Meaning: an E element whose "foo" attribute value is exactly equal to "bar".

In your case get element `#subcategory` with "name" attribute value is exactly equal to "CBC" and change is attribute to selected.

```js
var subCategorySelected = "CBC";    
$('#subCategory [name='+subCategorySelected+']').attr('selected','selected');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="subCategory" class="style_1">
     <option name="All" value="16,17,19,18,8,94" >All</option>
     <option name="CBC" value="94" >CBC</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Though it can be done using javascript but if you want it to be default selected you can do using [**selected**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) attribute

```
<select id="subCategory" class="style_1">
     <option name="All" value="16,17,19,18,8,94" >All</option>
     <option name="CBC" value="94" selected>CBC</option>
</select>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/8q6ko7fn/)

Comment: title says using Jquery this is not using Jquery

Comment: it is also  tagged with html

Answer (score 1):

You Can use simply like this.

```
var subCategorySelected = "CBC";  
$('#subCategory > [name="'+subCategorySelected+'"]').prop('selected','true')
```

```js
var subCategorySelected = "CBC";  
$('#subCategory > [name="'+subCategorySelected+'"]').prop('selected','true')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="subCategory" class="style_1">
     <option name="All" value="16,17,19,18,8,94" >All</option>
     <option name="CBC" value="94" >CBC</option>
</select>
```